# Deploying to heroku using bit bucket repo

Tags: heroku, bitbucket

I currently have a private repo on bitbucket which i would like to deploy to heroku.

Been looking around but finding it difficult to find any related info.

Can anyone assist

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you are hosting the repository on BitBucket, as opposed to GitHub or GitLab, makes no difference.

Just follow the [deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) support page from Heroku.

You simply need to create the application (unless you have one):

```
$ heroku create
```

At that point you should have the Heroku git remote URL:

```
$  git remote -v
```

Then you can deploy:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Please make sure to read the article I linked as it contains a more detailed explanation.